# compare one value with many value that result from subquery in sql server

Tags: sql-server-2008

how to compare one value with many that result from subquery

```
if(select COUNT(si.s_id)--==========>1  check if student has 4 passed courses
from students.student_study_subjects,students.study_info si,students.subjects,admins.years
where students.student_study_subjects.degree>=students.subjects.min_degree 
AND students.student_study_subjects.subj_code=students.subjects.subj_code
AND si.d_id=students.student_study_subjects.d_id
AND si.year=admins.years.year_num
AND si.year=(select max(admins.years.year_num)-1 from admins.years)
group by si.d_id,si.year)=4
begin 
insert into study_info
(s_id,year,dept_id,s_state,group_num)
select students.study_info.s_id,max(admins.years.year_num),students.study_info.dept_id,'new',students.study_info.group_num+1
from students.study_info,admins.years
group by students.study_info.s_id,students.study_info.dept_id,students.study_info.group_num
end
```

in general i want to insert into table some values if this subquery return value that equal 4

Comment: I didn't see any subquery in your post. There are only for courses or count may be different.

Comment: What is the problem? Does this produce an error? What doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Store the `output(count)` in a variable .
2. Check that variable equals to 4.
3. If it is then you can run the insert query

Comment: count function return (selected value) more than one value(there are many students that have 4 pass course) so we can't store more than one value(returned by count aggregate function) to variable

Comment: I suppose the query says that you are checking the count .
select COUNT(si.s_id)from Table1....

Comment: U can use a variable
Declare @count as int
select count =COUNT(si.s_id)from Table1.... 
if(@count==4) 
Begin
--Rest of Code---
End